# OAuth 1 Authorization Header with RestTemplate

Tags: spring, oauth, resttemplate

I'm trying to connect to DropBox API via OAuth 1. I have app key and app secret. I need access token and access secret.

I've tried to use DropBox SDK but couldn't find how to do it (current tutorial explains OAuth 2)

I've followed this tutorial and it works via cURL: https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2012/07/using-oauth-1-0-with-the-plaintext-signature-method/

I could not make that POST request with that header via RestTemplate:

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT",
oauth_consumer_key="<app-key>", oauth_token="<request-token>",
oauth_signature="<app-secret>&<request-token-secret>"
```

I've tried that:

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder().build();

```
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory rf =
            (HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) restTemplate.getRequestFactory();
    rf.setReadTimeout(1 * 1_000);
    rf.setConnectTimeout(1 * 1_000);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Authorization: ", "OAuth");
    headers.set("oauth_version", "1.0");
    headers.set("oauth_signature_method", "PLAINTEXT");
    headers.set("oauth_consumer_key", APP_KEY);
    headers.set("oauth_signature", APP_SECRET);

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

    Object result = restTemplate.postForEntity(
            "https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token",
            entity,
            Object.class)
```

It results with 400 HTTP Bad Request Error. How can I do it with RestTemplate?

Comment: Hello @kamaci did you get answer ?

Comment: Just cause i happened to fall on this post. In your example you dont follow what the site you linked says. Auth1 header is just 1 header and not multiple. So for starters I suggest try to merge those 5 headers in 1. The key is "Authorization" and the value are the rest which is called authorization string.  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/blob/master/spring-social-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/oauth1/OAuth1Template.java check line 197.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on this for a while until I could find a solution for myself.

```
 Object result = restClient.postData("https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token",
            getHeaders(), entity, Object.class);
```

**For Headers**

```
private HttpHeaders getHeaders() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        InvalidKeyException {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, getAuthHeader());
    return headers;
}

private String getAuthHeader() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        InvalidKeyException {
    String randomNumber = generateRandomString();
    String oauthNonce = getMd5(randomNumber);
    Long oauthTimestamp = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
    String baseString = "POST&"+
            URLEncoder.encode( URL , StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) + "&" +
            URLEncoder.encode(
                    ("deploy=" + DEPLOY +
                            + "&oauth_consumer_key=" + CONSUMER_KEY
                            + "&oauth_nonce=" + oauthNonce
                            + "&oauth_signature_method=" + "HMAC-SHA1"+
                            + "&oauth_timestamp=" + oauthTimestamp
                            + "&oauth_token=" + TOKEN
                            + "&oauth_version= 1.0"
                            + "&realm=" + REALM
                            + "&script=" + SCRIPT),StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()
            );
    String sigString = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_SECRET,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())
            + "&" + URLEncoder.encode(TOKEN_SECRET,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
    String signature= generateSignature(baseString,sigString,"HmacSHA1");
    String headers= " OAuth realm=\""+ URLEncoder.encode(
            REALM,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) + "\", "
            + "oauth_consumer_key=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(
                    CONSUMER_KEY,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) + "\", "
            + "oauth_token=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(TOKEN,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) + "\", "
            + "oauth_signature_method=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(
                    "HMAC-SHA1",StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) + "\", "
            + "oauth_timestamp=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(
                    String.valueOf(oauthTimestamp).substring(0,10),StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) + "\", "
            + "oauth_nonce=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(oauthNonce,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) + "\", "
            + "oauth_version=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(
                    "1.0",StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) + "\", "
            + "oauth_signature=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(signature,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) + "\" ";
    return headers;
}
```

The fields SCRIPT, DEPLOY and REALM if they are not necessary for you, remove them

Addicional methods

```
public static String getMd5(String input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(input.getBytes());
    BigInteger no = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest);
    StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder();
    String hashText = no.toString(16);
    bld.append(hashText);
    while (hashText.length() < 32) {
        bld.append("0");
    }
    return bld.toString();
}
public static String generateSignature(String msg, String keyString, String algoritmo) throws InvalidKeyException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    String digest;

    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), algoritmo);
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algoritmo);
    mac.init(key);
    byte[] bytes = mac.doFinal(msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
    digest = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);

    return digest;
}

private String generateRandomString() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    int largo=20;
    String [] carateres = ("0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,"
            + "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,S").split(",");
    StringBuilder randomString = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
    for(int i=0; i<largo; i++){
        randomString.append(carateres[random.nextInt((carateres.length - 1))]);
    }
    return randomString.toString();
}
```

I hope it helps someone, greetings